# Repeating the same operations in SQL SELECT

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am parsing a column into different tables and I have an operation that keeps repeating itself. Is there a way to avoid the redundancy, e.g., define a variable?
This is how my query looks like:

```
SELECT 
  CAST(CONCAT('0x', composed) as INT64)>>1 AS FIRST_VALUE, 
  CAST(CONCAT('0x', composed) as INT64)>>2 AS SECOND_VALUE, 
  ...
```

and I would like to have something like:

```
SELECT 
  INTERMEDIATE_VALUE = CAST(CONCAT('0x', composed) as INT64)
  INTERMEDIATE_VALUE>>1 AS FIRST_VALUE, 
  INTERMEDIATE_VALUE>>2 AS SECOND_VALUE, 
  ...
```

so that the cast/concat operation only takes place once per value instead of n times.

**Edit:**
I would also like to use the INTERMEDIATE_VALUE with a WHERE clause

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: I am using google big query with standard sql

Comment: what does `>>` represent ?

Comment: @Steven Probably a bit shift operation, but +1 to your answer.

Comment: @Steven yes, it is a bit shift operation. I forgot to mention, I would also like to filter on those variables

Comment: should I edit the question or should I open a new one?

Comment: @Aba you can add `where` clause using `INTERMEDIATE_VALUE` in my solution

Comment: @Steven thank you, I am marking your solution as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the easy solution :

```
select 
  INTERMEDIATE_VALUE>>1 AS FIRST_VALUE, 
  INTERMEDIATE_VALUE>>2 AS SECOND_VALUE, 
  ....
from (
     select CAST(CONCAT('0x', composed) as INT64) as INTERMEDIATE_VALUE 
     from .... 
) 
where INTERMEDIATE_VALUE = 'something'
```

Comment: @Aba you can add `where` clause using `INTERMEDIATE_VALUE`

Answer (score 1):

Below is approach I found most optimal/clean for such cases (BigQuery Standard SQL)

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  INTERMEDIATE_VALUE>>1 AS FIRST_VALUE, 
  INTERMEDIATE_VALUE>>2 AS SECOND_VALUE,
  ...
FROM `project.dataset.your_table`, 
UNNEST([CAST(CONCAT('0x', composed) AS INT64)]) INTERMEDIATE_VALUE  
WHERE INTERMEDIATE_VALUE > <some_value>
```

For example

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.your_table` AS (
  SELECT '1' composed UNION ALL
  SELECT 'FF'
)
SELECT 
  composed,
  INTERMEDIATE_VALUE,
  INTERMEDIATE_VALUE>>1 AS FIRST_VALUE, 
  INTERMEDIATE_VALUE>>2 AS SECOND_VALUE
FROM `project.dataset.your_table`, 
UNNEST([CAST(CONCAT('0x', composed) AS INT64)]) INTERMEDIATE_VALUE  
WHERE INTERMEDIATE_VALUE > 10
```

gives result as

```sql
Row composed    INTERMEDIATE_VALUE  FIRST_VALUE SECOND_VALUE     
1   FF          255                 127         63
```